# Disk Usage Analysys..

Tags: 12.04, filesystem, disk, disk-usage

On my virtual Ubuntu Desktop (HD: 300 GB), Disk usage analyzer shows:

[image]

and the `df-l` command shows:

[image]

This is strange! If the root consumes only 59.6 GB, How the filesystem capacity says it uses 227.4 GB ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program tallies both files that you do not have read access to. The 59.6 GB probably only refers to the actual amount of data you can READ. The 227.4 GB is the total space used on the hard drive, readable or not.